# How to stop scrolling toolbar in coordinatorlayout

Tags: android, scroll, toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I am making a simple app. I use CoordinatorLayout and AppbarLayout, AppbarLayout contains two Toolbar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="hi"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="sign"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hil"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

   </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="call"/>


</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

```
public void call(View view) {
Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar1);
Toolbar toolbar2=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar2);
toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
toolbar2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

}

In normal, the First toolbar will scroll, but When I click on the button in NestedScrollView. The second toolbar should show, toolbar must pin at the top don't want to scroll.

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @kris Larson said.

The Toolbar, being a child of the AppBarLayout, gets its LayoutParams from the AppBarLayout. These layout params have the scroll flags that are set in the XML.

So, you get the AppBarLayout.LayoutParams from the Toolbar, and call `setScrollFlags()` to change the flags to the value you want.

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);  // or however you need to do it for your code
AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
params.setScrollFlags(0);  // clear all scroll flags
```

Comment: Sorry. I am new to stackoverflow. I can't add some code. Actually I have other button to revert changes. and scroll again with first toolbar.

Comment: what to do for that

Comment: @c49 you want to set visibility or Scrolling?

Comment: I want Scrolling. Thanks. It works. I used setScrollFlags(1) for scroll again

Comment: I upvoted. How to make it accepted ? I am a newbie. I don't know that